# Getting fixed headers when scrolling on tables

Tags: javascript, css, html-table

I have looked around a good portion on here and others trying to figure out how to get my headers to stay in one place when scrolling.  It seems like I need to involve "position:fixed" in my JSP but all it is doing is positioning my headers horribly in my `<div>` box.  If possible can see what I am possibly missing or is there a lot more needed.

Here is my mainEFT.jsp (I know my TD formatting is kind of mess):

```
  <article class="divBoxsum">
     <div style="height:300px; overflow:auto;">
         <table>
           <thead>
              <tr>
                  <th>SEL</th>
                  <th>Schedule Number</th>
                  <th>Contract Year</th>
                  <th>Creation Date</th>
                  <th>Num of Pay Recs</th>
                  <th>Schedule Total</th>
                  <th>Status</th>
                  <th>Status Date</th>
                  <th>Approval ID</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
             <c:forEach  var="row" items="${EFTresults}">
             <c:set var="sched" value="${row.getSCHEDULE_NUMBER()}" />
             <c:set var="eftyear" value="${row.getEFT_CONTRACT_YEAR()}" />
             <fmt:formatNumber var="schedTotl" value="${row.getTOTAL_AMOUNT()}" pattern="$##,###,##0.00"/>
                 <tr>
                   <td width="65px;"><input type="submit" 
                                   formaction="EFTscreen?action=detailEFT&scheduleNumber=${sched}&contractYear=${eftyear}"
                                   value="Select" style="height: 25px; width: 65px; background-color: #0C6;
                                   font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;   
                                   font-size:15px; font-weight:bold; color:#eee;" title="Select Schedule">
               </td>
               <td><c:out value="${row.getSCHEDULE_NUMBER()}" /></td>
                                <td><c:out value="${row.getEFT_CONTRACT_YEAR()}" /></td>
               <td width="165px";><c:out value="${row.getCREATION_DATE()}"/></td>
               <td width="50px";><c:out value="${row.getNUM_OF_PAY_RECORDS()}"/></td>
               <td style="text-align: right; padding-right: 10px;"><c:out value="${schedTotl}"/></td>
               <td><c:out value="${row.getSTATUS()}"/></td>
               <td width="205px";><c:out value="${row.getSTATUS_DATE()}"/>/td>
               <td><c:out value="${row.getAPPR_HUD_EMPLOYEE()}"/></td>
                </tr>
              </c:forEach>

           </tbody>
      </table>
   </div>

</article>
```

Here is my CSS:

```css
.divBoxsum {
  height: 350px; 
  width: 50%; 
  border: 1px solid #343131; 
  -moz-border-radius: 6px; 
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px; 
  border-radius: 6px; 
  display: block;
  margin-top: 35px;
  margin-left: 30px; 
  float: left;  
}

table {
  width: 95%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border: 0px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  font-style: normal; 
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-left: 10px; 
  margin-right: 175px;      
}

th { 
  background: #394065; 
  border-bottom-color: #16a085;
  color: white;             
}

td, th { 
  padding: 3px; 
  border: 1px solid black; 
  text-align: left; 
}
```

Comment: Can you use javascript or jQuery?  I'd suggest cloning the table head by itself, hiding it, positioning it fixed then show it when the table scrolls into view.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `position:fixed` in this instance.

You need to:

- declare an explicit `height` for `<tbody>`
- declare `overflow-y: scroll` for `<tbody>`

**Example:**

```css
thead, tbody {
display: block;
}

tbody {
height: 140px;
overflow-y: scroll;
}

th, td {
width: 120px;
border: 1px solid rgb(0,0,0);
}

th {
color: rgb(255,255,255);;
background-color: rgb(191,0,0);
}

td {
color: rgb(0,0,0);;
background-color: rgb(221,255,221);
}
```

```html
<table>
<thead>
<th>SEL</th>
<th>Schedule Number</th>
<th>Contract Year</th>
<th>Creation Date</th>
<th>Num of Pay Recs</th>
<th>Schedule Total</th>
<th>Status</th>
<th>Status Date</th>
<th>Approval ID</th>
</thead>

<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Cell 1</td>
<td>Cell 2</td>
<td>Cell 3</td>
<td>Cell 4</td>
<td>Cell 5</td>
<td>Cell 6</td>
<td>Cell 7</td>
<td>Cell 8</td>
<td>Cell 9</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Cell 1</td>
<td>Cell 2</td>
<td>Cell 3</td>
<td>Cell 4</td>
<td>Cell 5</td>
<td>Cell 6</td>
<td>Cell 7</td>
<td>Cell 8</td>
<td>Cell 9</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Cell 1</td>
<td>Cell 2</td>
<td>Cell 3</td>
<td>Cell 4</td>
<td>Cell 5</td>
<td>Cell 6</td>
<td>Cell 7</td>
<td>Cell 8</td>
<td>Cell 9</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Cell 1</td>
<td>Cell 2</td>
<td>Cell 3</td>
<td>Cell 4</td>
<td>Cell 5</td>
<td>Cell 6</td>
<td>Cell 7</td>
<td>Cell 8</td>
<td>Cell 9</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Cell 1</td>
<td>Cell 2</td>
<td>Cell 3</td>
<td>Cell 4</td>
<td>Cell 5</td>
<td>Cell 6</td>
<td>Cell 7</td>
<td>Cell 8</td>
<td>Cell 9</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Cell 1</td>
<td>Cell 2</td>
<td>Cell 3</td>
<td>Cell 4</td>
<td>Cell 5</td>
<td>Cell 6</td>
<td>Cell 7</td>
<td>Cell 8</td>
<td>Cell 9</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Cell 1</td>
<td>Cell 2</td>
<td>Cell 3</td>
<td>Cell 4</td>
<td>Cell 5</td>
<td>Cell 6</td>
<td>Cell 7</td>
<td>Cell 8</td>
<td>Cell 9</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Cell 1</td>
<td>Cell 2</td>
<td>Cell 3</td>
<td>Cell 4</td>
<td>Cell 5</td>
<td>Cell 6</td>
<td>Cell 7</td>
<td>Cell 8</td>
<td>Cell 9</td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td>Cell 1</td>
<td>Cell 2</td>
<td>Cell 3</td>
<td>Cell 4</td>
<td>Cell 5</td>
<td>Cell 6</td>
<td>Cell 7</td>
<td>Cell 8</td>
<td>Cell 9</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Cell 1</td>
<td>Cell 2</td>
<td>Cell 3</td>
<td>Cell 4</td>
<td>Cell 5</td>
<td>Cell 6</td>
<td>Cell 7</td>
<td>Cell 8</td>
<td>Cell 9</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Cell 1</td>
<td>Cell 2</td>
<td>Cell 3</td>
<td>Cell 4</td>
<td>Cell 5</td>
<td>Cell 6</td>
<td>Cell 7</td>
<td>Cell 8</td>
<td>Cell 9</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Cell 1</td>
<td>Cell 2</td>
<td>Cell 3</td>
<td>Cell 4</td>
<td>Cell 5</td>
<td>Cell 6</td>
<td>Cell 7</td>
<td>Cell 8</td>
<td>Cell 9</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Cell 1</td>
<td>Cell 2</td>
<td>Cell 3</td>
<td>Cell 4</td>
<td>Cell 5</td>
<td>Cell 6</td>
<td>Cell 7</td>
<td>Cell 8</td>
<td>Cell 9</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I tried moving the height and scroll from the DIV box to the TBODY section and it increased the height of the individual columns and still not getting a scroll bar.  Do I need to include a 'table-layout:auto;' command in the CSS as well?    The other issue is that your borders on the details aren't aligned with the headers which was a major headache when I tried it before.    Thanks for response

Comment: Oh sorry I should have done the 'full page' when I ran it.  the alignment is fine.  I see I didn't have  'display: block;' so maybe that was the missing ingrident

Comment: Still confused on how you are getting a table with a height of 140px and not just the height of each detail record in table at 140px?  Is the 'display:block' fixing this?  Also what is the significance of setting 'border-collapse' to separate instead of the collapse that I have.  Thanks

Comment: In my example, it's `tbody` which has an explicit height of `140px`. Neither `table` nor `thead` have any explicit height declared. There is no significance to the `border-collapse` property - you can set it to any value you like.